# How do I use ASCII (and not Unicode) in Python?

Tags: python, ascii

I'm trying to make a Caesar cipher encryptor/decryptor in Python, by getting the ASCII index of a letter and adding/subtracting from it. However, it seems to be using Unicode instead because I get letters with accents instead of just English alphabet letters. For example, if I enter the word 'weasel' and encrypt it by 2, what I get is 'yÞĿƲȗʃ'. How do I use ASCII?

Here is my code:

```py
    def manipulate(text, key, e_or_d):
        ciphertext = ''
        for i in text:
            asciiCode = ord(i)
            if e_or_d == 'e':
                key = ord(i) + key
            elif e_or_d == 'd':
                key = ord(i) - key
            newChar = chr(key)
            ciphertext += newChar
        if e_or_d == 'e':
                print('Here is your encrypted text: ')
        elif e_or_d == 'd':
            print('Here is your decrypted text: ')
        print(ciphertext)
    
    text = input('Enter text: ')
    e_or_d = input('Enter \'e\' for encryption or \'d\' for decryption: ')
    key = int(input('Enter encryption key: '))
    manipulate(text, key, e_or_d)
```

I used `chr` and `ord` here to turn an index into a character and identify the index of a character, respectively.

Sorry if this is incoherent and disorganised.

Comment: You are accumulating on `key` variable that arrives to the function. Try `new_ord = ord(i) + key` instead of `key = ord(i) + key` to keep `key` the same throughout i.e., what user supplied. Similar goes for decryption `if`.

Comment: another thing to note is a-z only range from 97-122, so case like `manipulate("weasel", 4, "e")` will give you unexpected result and you need to handle it.

Comment: You should probably read Joel Spolsky's [_The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excluses!)_](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) All Python 3 strings are Unicode strings; you just have to understand how Unicode is organized. In brief, the first 128 characters are the ASCII subset.

Answer (score 2):

It is taking using ascii. You are increasing `key` by `ord(i)` for every iteration in the loop. So it is not constant. Use a new variable instead of `key` and it should work.

```py
def manipulate(text, key, e_or_d):
    ciphertext = ''
    for i in text:
        asciiCode = ord(i)
        if e_or_d == 'e':
            temp = ord(i) + key
        elif e_or_d == 'd':
            temp = ord(i) - key
        newChar = chr(temp)
        ciphertext += newChar
    if e_or_d == 'e':
        print('Here is your encrypted text: ')
    elif e_or_d == 'd':
        print('Here is your decrypted text: ')
    print(ciphertext)
```

**NOTE: I think using boolean values for `e_or_d` would be better. Also keep your variable names consistent, like using camel case only or using `_` only.**

Answer (score 2):

There are few things to notice:

1. you are changing key in every loop while it should keep the same, so you need another variable to save result
2. `ord(a)-ord(z)` range from 97-122, you may have unexpected result even after changing point 1, for example, `manipulate("a", 1, "d")` is `` ` `` and `manipulate("z", 1, "e")` is `{`, as they are out of range after manipulate.

I suppose the user will only input lowercase letter, if they will input uppercase letter or other character, extra checking is needed, here's the code changing just 2 points above:

```
def manipulate(text, key, e_or_d):
    ciphertext = ''
    if e_or_d == "e":
        step = 1
        action = "encrypted"
    elif e_or_d == "d":
        step = -1
        action = "decrypted"
    for i in text:
        # * step means + key in encryption and - key in decryption
        new_ord = ord(i) + (key * step)
        # check if new_ord is inside the range of a-z
        if 97 <= new_ord <= 122:
            new_char = chr(new_ord)
        else:
            # if new_ord > 122, it will - 26, elif new_ord < 97, it will + 26
            new_char = chr(new_ord - (26 * step))
        ciphertext += new_char
    print(f'Here is your {action} text: ')
    print(ciphertext)

text = input('Enter text: ')
key = int(input('Enter encryption key: '))
e_or_d = input('Enter \'e\' for encryption or \'d\' for decryption: ')
manipulate(text, key, e_or_d)
```

Output:

```
Enter text: weasel
Enter encryption key: 2
Enter 'e' for encryption or 'd' for decryption: e
Here is your encrypted text:
ygcugn

Enter text: a
Enter encryption key: 1
Enter 'e' for encryption or 'd' for decryption: d
Here is your decrypted text:
z

Enter text: z
Enter encryption key: 1
Enter 'e' for encryption or 'd' for decryption: e
Here is your encrypted text:
a
```